# Excel PMT on 6 months financing

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am able to use the PMT function in Excel for periods of 12, 24 and 36 months. But I am falling short of understanding how to use the function for 6 months periods.

Let's suppose I have a debt of **10 000$** and the annual interest from the bank is **10%**.

If I pay monthly and I want to pay within the first year, I will do the following formula :

`=PMT(10%/12;12;10000)`

But what if I need to pay in 6 months?

At first I thought of doing

```
=PMT(10%/6;6;10000)
```

But this gives me **more interest** than paying over a year!

I searched various websites without luck.

My last resort was the [official Excel website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pmt-function-0214da64-9a63-4996-bc20-214433fa6441) : they actually have an example of a payment over 10 months. Following their code, I would write :

```
=NPM(10%/12;6;10000)
```

The result is smaller than 12 months' interest (yay!), but why!?

Why do we calculate the interest over 12 months, and not 6? I can't seem to understand that part.

Comment: Because it is an *annual* interest rate and you are using months as your unit. In the "Remarks" section of that same link: "Make sure that you are consistent about the units you use for specifying rate and nper. If you make monthly payments on a four-year loan at an annual interest rate of 12 percent, use 12%/12 for rate and 4*12 for nper. If you make annual payments on the same loan, use 12 percent for rate and 4 for nper."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about understanding how loans work

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're adjusting an interest rate which is **independent** of the time you pay it off in. Technically PMT takes an interest rate equal to the period of time you are considering.

So if you're talking about paying over 6 months with an annual interest rate the correct formula is:

```
=PMT(10%/12;6;10000)
```

`10%/12` is the 10% annual interest converted to a monthly period. 6 is the number of months, and 10000 is the value of the loan. `10%/6` is actually a bi-monthly interest rate.

Technically if you're compounding annually and pay off $10,000 in 5 years, at 10% p.a. the formula would be:

```
=PMT(10%;5;10000)
```